# Points Plotted Without XY coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, coordinates

I am currently trying to figure out how a set of points were plotted without full XY coordinates. I was given Y coordinates, but not X and there are points plotted on a map. I think these points were just placed by drawing points/creating features. Is there any way I can figure out the X coordinates from the Y?

[image]

Comment: The image shows a "Point" geometry, which has both X and Y (at least), so the Y field doesn't have to be correct (because it isn't used).

Comment: Okay, great thank you! Am I able to extract those numbers out?

Comment: Did they gave you like this or did you export it from an Excel ?

Comment: The data was given to me like this. I'm trying to build a database of all manholes in a certain area and I would like the X coordinates to better fill out the data table.

Comment: Because I was wondering if they had gave you in an Excel, the X table might have been "hide"

Answer (score 2):

Found out the solution. The shapefile was read only, I couldn't figure out how to edit the attribute table or create new features. In order to remedy this you have to exit ArcMap. Open the file explorer (or ArcCatalog) go to folder containing shapefile > properties > uncheck read only. Once the shapefile was editable a tool called "Add XY coordinates" was used under Data Management > Features > Add XY coodinates. Input desired shapefile and it outputs XY coordinates in the attribute table.

Comment: If you have the ArcGIS Pro, it will automatically filled it in for you if you open the X,Y Data Coordinates if I remember right. I did this last week. If you did this the X coordinates probably would have either show up or not... just FYI

Comment: If you use operating system tools to change a read-only `.shp`, you'll also need to change the `.shx`, `.dbf` and all the other files with the same prefix as well, or you just might be able to corrupt the data.